# Nuxt app referencing non-existant JS files - getting 404 errors

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

We've been working on our first Nuxt app for a while & everything has been going fine.

Recently one of my colleagues made changes to the app & when we pushed those to our staging server the app broke.

The Console is showing a number of 404 erors for the `.js` (& only the `.js` files):

[image]

But looking at the (Ubuntu/ Apache2/ Node) server those files don't exist in the `/_nuxt/` directory:

[image]

If I build the app on my local computer it runs fine under my local Apache2/Node server. In fact the filenames referenced on my local computer are the same as those on our staging server.

Does anyone have any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: Probably some configuration issue on production, configuration file, permission or proxy. Also what was changed when app started crashing?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by restarting the Node server via PM2: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

`pm2 start`